Should I edit an old question or create a new one?
About three months ago, I posted this question. While it got six upvotes and I accepted an answer, it was closed because it was said to be opinion-based. I want to make it clear that I am not making an argument against its closure.
I have since formulated a question that better articulates what I am asking for and makes my question less opinion-based. Should I edit my original question or post a new one?

It really depends. In general, I'd advise against question rewrites that invalidate answers. It may not be possible to fully avoid it, but if the core question gets shifted a new question would make sense.

You might consider including the question in your post here to get a read on whether it should be an edit to the existing post, a new question, or neither (for example, it may be deemed still to be "opinion based").
